# How do I know that I need to add an insole to my shoe?

Tags: shoes

I am trying to learn more about shoes, but for the near term goal, I have this query - how do I really know that I need an insole? How to select the right insole that I need?

Comment: How bad are your knee problems?  Do they only show up when you're hiking?  Only when you're hiking very long distances?  Do they affect you when you're walking around day-to-day, or when you're trying to sleep?

Comment: I have the knee problem when walking or standing for few hours like shopping. But that really varies on the shoes I wear too. SO I believe that its a combination of my knee problem and the right shoes. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Yeah...  you might need to see a doctor.  I don't have any particularly great advice to give you.  Its hard to find a good doctor.  Are there any local running clubs in your area?  You could ask around with them, maybe find a doctor / and or physical therapist that is used to helping active people solve their knee problems...  But, if there's a certain pair of shoes that seems to help, I'd suggest you keep wearing them in the mean time.

Comment: FWIW - I've been to the knee doctor a couple times in the past 10 years.  I only got prescribed surgery when I had an injury that was very acute.  The other time (8 years ago), the doctor recommended a conservative (non surgery) solution, and that worked very well ( until I reinjured it separately, years later).  Find a good doctor in your area, and a good PT (that deals with athletes or runners) and you should be on the right path.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. You should ask to a orthopedic doctor about it (possibly one specialized in sport), and have proper measurement taken. Choosing a bad insole that goes against your leg building might seriously damage your joints and knees. Don't have a shopkeeper decide either, they are NOT qualified to know which of your leg is shorter or longer, how your knee and ankles turn, and if you need a specific lift for one or both of your feet.

Comment: +1.  Definitely find a doctor or physical therapist that is used to dealing with athletes... Maybe runners?  But don't presume that every ortho is good at dealing with athletes.  Some ortho's are pure surgeons, and like to cut.

Comment: Seriously I am scared to visit an Ortho for the same reason :)

Comment: @DavidR: LOL at *,and like to cut* :D But True Anyway :(